# Minimum value string

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm

Given string of digits like "72388" and int n, delete n characters from the sting such the resulting string contains minimal number representation, you must preserve relative position of digits. Example: if st="72388" and n=2, the answer is 238.

Below solution does not seem to work for all the cases. How can we reduce a string to minimal string ?

Solution :
Idea here is scan from left to right delete a char if it is greater than next char in string array and prev char. if the number of chars deleted are less than 'n' by the end of the iteration, repeat the same iteration from end to start of the string.

```
char *
min_string(char *str, int n)
{
static char buf[100] = "";
int len = strlen(str);
int k = -1;
int count = 0;
int i;
char prev, curr, next;

if(len == 0 || len < n)
return -1;

if(len == n)
return 0;

prev = str[0];
for(i=1; i<len-1 && count<=n; i++)
{
curr = str[i];
next = str[i+1];
if(curr > next && curr > prev)
{
    count++;
    continue;
}
else if(curr < next && curr <= prev)
{
    count++;
    prev = curr;
    buf[k] = curr;
}
else
{
    buf[++k] = curr;
}
}

if(count < n)
{
count = 0;
k = len - n;
prev = buf[k - 1] = str[len-1];
for(i=len-2; i>0; i--)
{
    curr = str[i];
    next = str[i-1];
    if(curr > next && curr > prev)
    {
    count++;
    continue;
    }
    else if(curr < next && curr <= prev)
    {
    count++;
    prev = curr;
    buf[k] = curr;
    }
    else
    {
    buf[--k] = curr;
    }
}

printf("Resulted string     :   %s\n", buf);
return buf;
}
else
{
for(; i<len; i++)
{
    buf[++k] = str[i];
}

printf("Resulted string ascending   :   %s\n", buf);
return buf;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have an algorithm for this that *doesn't* run in linear time?

Comment: Algorithm that I have implemented does not seem to work for particular cases. So I dont know of any algorithm which functions correctly in all the cases

Comment: Why don't you post your current approach?

Comment: can you please re-phrase your question. I am unable to understand what is the logic you are using here.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a few hints to not spoil the fun:

The order of deletions doesn't affect the outcome. Therefore you can delete digits one by one, every time deleting the digit that makes the number the smallest possible.

The digit to delete will be the leftmost one that is greater than its successor.

If there is no such digit, the digits make an increasing sequence, and the digit to delete is the last one.